# Custom AlertDialogBox does not show from different class

Tags: android, android-alertdialog, customdialog

I have a custom layout for my dialog box which shows the available product of a store in my app:

> popstoreproduct.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@color/backgroundgrey">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_marginVertical="20dp">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtlist"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="P R O D U C T"
            android:textSize="16dp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:textColor="@color/text1"/>
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="L I S T"
            android:textSize="16dp"
            android:textColor="@color/text1"/>
    </LinearLayout>
    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/poprecycler"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="500dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:overScrollMode="never"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

I have to use this layout as dialog in different activities so I have created a class that has a function which calls the dialog from MainActivity

> Utility.java

```
public class Utility {

    public Utility() {
    }

    public void popStoreProduct(Context context,ArrayList<Stock> mainlist,ArrayList<Stock> menuList){
        final AlertDialog.Builder mBuild = new AlertDialog.Builder(context,R.style.DialogSlideAnim);
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.popstoreproduct,null);
        final RecyclerView precycler =(RecyclerView)layout.findViewById(R.id.poprecycler);
        LinearLayoutManager playoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(context);
        precycler.setLayoutManager(playoutManager);
        precycler.setHasFixedSize(true);
        AdapterPopStoreProduct pAdapter = new AdapterPopStoreProduct(context,mainlist,menuList);
        precycler.setAdapter(pAdapter);
        mBuild.setView(layout);
        final AlertDialog dialog = mBuild.create();
        dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        dialog.getWindow().getAttributes().gravity = Gravity.BOTTOM |Gravity.CLIP_HORIZONTAL;
        dialog.show();
    }

}
```

When I run the app and call for the function in my main activity, it crashes and gives the following error that points to the dialog.show() line:

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity.
> at com.example.myapp.Classes.Utility.popStoreProduct(Utility.java:288)

I don't understand what is wrong with the code. Please Help
PS: I have use slide animation in my dialog that slides from the bottom.

Answer (score 0):

show your `styles` file and `Activity`s manifest declaration. as the error say your style for `Activity` must be/extends `Theme.AppCompat`. for example:

```
android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light"
```

you can also set this theme for all Activities adding above line to `<application` tag instead of each `Activity` declaration

Comment: <style name="DialogAnimation">
        <item name="android:windowEnterAnimation">@anim/slide_up_dialog</item>
        <item name="android:windowExitAnimation">@anim/slide_out_down</item>
    </style>

    <style name="DialogSlideAnim" parent="@android:style/Theme.Dialog">
        <item name="android:windowAnimationStyle">@style/DialogAnimation</item>
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@null</item>
        <item name="android:windowFrame">@null</item>
        <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    </style>

Comment: how to extend it

Comment: `name="DialogSlideAnim" parent="@android:style/Theme.Dialog"` -> `name="DialogSlideAnim" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Dialog"`. all styles should extend `AppCompat`s